# Pycrypto for windows 7 python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, windows-7-x64, pycrypto

Ok so i am trying to encrypt /decrypt a .txt file as part of a longer script.

So i am trying to install PyCrypto for windows 7 64bit python 3.5 using this link, https://github.com/sfbahr/PyCrypto-Wheels.

But alias keeps failing. With the a bit of investigation i believe it is the wheel so i have tried to upgrade without success with the following error:
"

```
could not find a version that satisifes the requirement wheel--upgrade
no matching distribution found for wheel--upgrade
```

.

Any ideas? all i want to achieve is encrypt /decrypt a .txt file with aes or similar on 3.5 win7.

Comment: Are you typing `wheel--upgrade` when you need `wheel --upgrade`, with a space before the `--`?

Comment: will try that now thanks

Comment: same error PP :(